# detect selections of 2 sets of radio buttons in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have a web page which asks the user two simple yes-no questions. Under each question there's a set of two radio buttons in which the user can choose either yes or no.

```
<p>Question 1 yes or no?</p>

<input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1-y" value="Yes">Yes
<input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1-n" value="No">No 

<p>Question 2 yes or no?</p>

<input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2-y" value="Yes">Yes
<input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2-n" value="No">No
```

If the user chooses yes for BOTH questions, it needs to display some HTML which will provide a link to a certain page. If the users answers no to one or both of the questions, then some alternative HTML will appear which will display another message.

There can't be a submit button like a form and this has to be a javascript/jquery based solution, not server side. The page needs to:

1) Detect when both sets of questions have been answered. Then
2) Instantly display certain HTML depending on if either a) YES has been answered to both, or b) if a NO has been given once or more.

Essentially, the logic should be something along the lines of:

```
if( /*both radio buttons answered*/ ){
   if( /*both answers are yes*/ ){
      /*show HTML set 1*/  
   } else {
      /*show HTML set 2*/
   }
}
```

I have tried looking at questions on this site, but I can't seem to find a solution to this specific problem. Let me know if anything needs clarifying.

Thanks very much!

Comment: What specific issue do you have? Do you have an issue detecting when a user submits an answer? Is the issue figuring out what answer they gave? Is the issue dynamically displaying HTML?

Comment: Have you looked into something like jQuery?

Comment: Essentially, I need to a) detect when both sets of radio buttons have been answered, then b)find out what answer they gave for both questions. I don't actually have an issue dynamically displaying the HTML afterwards. I could handle that.

Comment: I am looking for a jquery solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different solution:

```
$( "input" ).change(function() {

 var buttons = jQuery("input:radio:checked").get();
 var values = $.map(buttons, function(element) {
    return $(element).attr("value");
 });

 if(values == "Yes,Yes") {
   alert("both yes");
 }
 else {
  //do something else
 }

});
```

Demo: [Multiple Radiobuttons](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/ahn26wb6/1/)

Don't like to check the string like that but could be adjusted in a proper way.

Comment: Great. I modified it slightly and wrapped the if-else statement in another if statement to check if `values.length == 2` first, as it should only run when both questions have been submitted first. Otherwise it was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#yep").hide();
$("#nope").hide();  

$(".nones").click(function(){
  $("#yep").hide();
  $("#nope").show();
});

$(".yipis").click(function(){
   var checkeo = 1;
   $( ".yipis" ).each(function( index ) {
      if($(this).is(":checked") == false)
      {
          checkeo = 0;
      };
    });
    if(checkeo){
        $("#nope").hide(); 
        $("#yep").show();
    }
});    
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/84o46mqd/

Comment: I like this answer, very close but no cigar. The HTML needs to display as soon as BOTH questions have been answered. This one fires off on the first 'no' answer, we need to have both answers first before showing the #yep or #nope divs.

Comment: You write this: `If the users answers no to one or both of the questions, then some alternative HTML will appear which will display another message.` ....One or both for NO....cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible way to access the values you want. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2twLszsd/)

HTML

```
<p>Question 1 yes or no?</p>

<input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1-y" value="Yes">Yes
<input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1-n" value="No">No 

<p>Question 2 yes or no?</p>

<input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2-y" value="Yes">Yes
<input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2-n" value="No">No

<p>
    <input type="button" id="finished" value="Submit" />
</p>

<div id="htmlarea"></div>
```

JavaScript

I find that jQuery [`is()` function](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and the [pseudo class `:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) are helped when reading radio buttons.

```
$("#finished").click(function() {
    var q1y = $("#q1-y").is(":checked");
    var q1n = $("#q1-n").is(":checked");
    var q2y = $("#q2-y").is(":checked");
    var q2n = $("#q2-n").is(":checked");

    if (q1y && q2y) {
        $("#htmlarea").html("Both yes");
    } else if (q1n && q2n) {
        $("#htmlarea").html("Both no");
    } else {
        var html = "";
        if (q1y) html += "Q1 yes. ";
        if (q1n) html += "Q1 no. ";
        if (q2y) html += "Q2 yes. ";
        if (q2n) html += "Q2 no. ";
        if (html=="") html = "None selected";
        $("#htmlarea").html(html);
    }
});
```

Instead of setting the HTML text, use `window.location.href = "http://someurl.com";` if you want to redirect to another webpage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there can't be a submit button. The jquery needs to check the answers as soon as both radio button questions have been submitted, not when you click the 'submit' button.

Answer (score 0):

One approach, given the following HTML (note the custom `data-*` attributes in the appended `<div>` elements, used to identify which choice those elements relate to):

```
<p>Question 1 yes or no?</p>
<input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1-y" value="Yes" />Yes
<input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1-n" value="No" />No
<p>Question 2 yes or no?</p>
<input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2-y" value="Yes" />Yes
<input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2-n" value="No" />No

<div class="result" data-relatesTo="Yes">All choices are 'yes'</div>
<div class="result" data-relatesTo="No">All choices are 'no'</div>
```

Which works with the following jQuery:

```
// caching the radio elements on the page:
var radios = $('input[type="radio"]'),
// getting the number of unique radio 'groups':
    radioGroups = $.unique($('input[type="radio"]').map(function () {
        return this.name;
    }).get());

// binding an anonymous function as a change-event handler:
radios.change(function () {
    // getting all the checked radio inputs:
    var checked = radios.filter(':checked'),
    // creating an object that maps to the relevant values/choices to be made:
        choice = {
            'yes': checked.filter(function () {
                return this.value.toLowerCase() === 'yes';
            }).get(),
                'no': checked.filter(function () {
                return this.value.toLowerCase() === 'no';
            }).get()
        };

    // if all groups have a checked radio input:
    if (checked.length === radioGroups.length) {
        // iterate over the '.result' div elements:
        $('div.result').each(function (i, el) {
            // using 'toggle(switch)' to show/hide the element,
            // the switch tests whether the choice related to the current
            // element is equal to the number of radioGroups. If it is,
            // it's shown, otherwise it's hidden.
            $(this).toggle(choice[el.getAttribute('data-relatesTo').toLowerCase()].length === radioGroups.length);
        });
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xkkgaura/).

Alternatively, with the same HTML, the following jQuery approach also works:

```
var radios = $('input[type="radio"]'),
    radioGroups = $.unique($('input[type="radio"]').map(function () {
        return this.name;
    }).get());

radios.change(function () {
    var checked = radios.filter(':checked'),
    // getting all the unique chosen values (in lowercase):
        opts = $.unique(checked.map(function(){
            return this.value.toLowerCase();
        }).get());

    if (checked.length === radioGroups.length) {
        // hide all the '.result' elements:
        $('div.result').hide()
            // filter the 'div.result' elements:
            .filter(function(){
                // if the number of opts (chosen values) is 1
                // (all choices are the same) and the 'data-relatesTo' attribute
                // of the current element we're filtering is equal to that single
                // option, then the element is retained in the selector
                return opts.length === 1 && this.getAttribute('data-relatesTo').toLowerCase() === opts[0].toLowerCase();
        })
        // and so we show it:
        .show();
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xkkgaura/1/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute).
  - [`String.prototype.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
- jQuery:

  - [`$.unique()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
  - [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).
  - [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).